# Statistic (frequency of occurrence % ecc..) analysis of a txt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, statistics

I cannot figure out what is the method i should use to find out:

- frequency of occurrence
- values that appear in the file

For example my file is:

```
  xxxxx, yyyy , 79
  xxxxx, yyyy , 80
  xxxxx, yyyy , 79
  xxxxx, yyyy , 81
  xxxxx, yyyy , 80
```

and i want to find out that 79 has 40% of occurrence like 80 and 81 has 20%.
How can i do that? (without R if it's possible...)

I need those because i want to plot an histogram using gnuplot. Can you also show me how to use the values just calculated to plot one histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some combination of sort and uniq might do the trick. You could start with

```
cat file  | cut -d ',' -f 3 | sort | uniq --count > file.1
```

To plot in gnuplot, do

```
gnuplot
plot [78:82][0:3] "file.1" using 2:1 with boxes
```

The left braces `[78:82]` set the xrange, the other the yrange. This could be determined automatically, but a short look at the file to determine min/max values works well in this demo case.

Depending on your OS and configuration, this could be enough. You might need to also use `set terminal` and `set output`. (start gnuplot and say help, there is an in-program help)

Comment: sorry i can't figure out how to use that, and i'm still stuck

Comment: hopefully, this helps, just say if you still need help